# Gauss-Jordan elimination returning only zeros

Tags: c++, c

My code is returning zero for all values and I'm not sure why.  I'm supposed to solve using Gauss-Jordan elimination.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
int main()
{
 double a[N][N+1]={{3.55618, 5.87317, 7.84934, 5.6951, 3.84642, 9.15038, -1.68539, 5.03067, 7.63384, -1.75626},
{-4.82893, 8.38177, -0.301221, 5.10182, -4.1169, -6.09145, -3.95675, -2.33365, 1.3969, 6.54555},
{-7.64196, 5.66605, 3.20481, 1.55619, -1.19814, 9.79288, 5.35547, 5.86109, 4.95544, -9.35749},
{-2.95914, -9.16958, 7.3216, 2.39876, -8.1302, -7.55135, -2.37718, 7.29694, 5.9867, 8.5401},
{-8.42043, -0.369407, -5.4102, -8.00545, 9.22153, 3.96454, 5.38499, 0.438365, 0.419677, 4.17166},
{6.02952, 4.57728, 5.46424, 3.52915, -1.01135, -3.74686, 8.14264, -8.86961, -2.88114, 1.29821},
{0.519819, -6.16655, 1.13216, 2.75811, -1.05975, 4.20286, -3.45764, 0.763558, -0.281287, -9.76168},
{5.15737, -9.67481, 9.29904, -3.93334, 9.12785, -4.25208, -6.1652, 2.5375, 0.139195, 2.00106},
{-4.30784, 1.40711, -6.97966, -9.29715, 5.17234, 2.42634, 1.88818, -2.05526, -3.7679, 3.3708},
{-4.65418, 7.18118, 6.51338, 3.13249, 0.188456, -16.85599, 7.21435, -2.93417, 1.06061, 1.10807}};
 double pivot,d;
 int i,j,k;
 for(k=0; k<N; k++)
 {
     pivot=a[k][k];
     for(j=k; j<N+1; j++) 
        a[k][j]=a[k][j]/pivot;
     for(i=0; i<N; i++)
     {
        if(i != k)
        {
           d=a[i][k];
           for(j=k; j<N+1; j++) a[i][j]=a[i][j]-d*a[k][j];
        }
     }
 }
for(i=0; i<N; i++)
   printf("x[%d]=%lf\n", i+1, a[i][N]);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input array is of size `[10][11]` but your input values are of size `[10][10]`.  Therefore your rightmost column is full of zeroes, which means the output will be all zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :-   (N in place of N+1)    :-)

double a[N][N]={{3.55618, 5.87317, 7.84934, 5.6951, 3.84642, 9.15038, -1.68539,        
                   5.03067, 7.63384, -1.75626},
                  {-4.82893, 8.38177, -0.301221, 5.10182, -4.1169, -6.09145, -3.95675,     
                   -2.33365, 1.3969, 6.54555},
                  {-7.64196, 5.66605, 3.20481, 1.55619, -1.19814, 9.79288, 5.35547,  
                   5.86109, 4.95544, -9.35749},
                  {-2.95914, -9.16958, 7.3216, 2.39876, -8.1302, -7.55135, -2.37718,         
                   7.29694, 5.9867, 8.5401},
                  {-8.42043, -0.369407, -5.4102, -8.00545, 9.22153, 3.96454, 5.38499, 
                   0.438365, 0.419677, 4.17166},
                  {6.02952, 4.57728, 5.46424, 3.52915, -1.01135, -3.74686, 8.14264,       
                   -8.86961, -2.88114, 1.29821},
                  {0.519819, -6.16655, 1.13216, 2.75811, -1.05975, 4.20286, -3.45764,   
                   0.763558, -0.281287, -9.76168},
                  {5.15737, -9.67481, 9.29904, -3.93334, 9.12785, -4.25208, -6.1652,    
                   2.5375, 0.139195, 2.00106},
                  {-4.30784, 1.40711, -6.97966, -9.29715, 5.17234, 2.42634, 1.88818,         
                   -2.05526, -3.7679, 3.3708},
                  {-4.65418, 7.18118, 6.51338, 3.13249, 0.188456, -16.85599, 7.21435,  
                   -2.93417, 1.06061, 1.10807}};
```